# Matching IDs preceded with "case" with SSIS script using C# regex

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I am using SSIS script component to extract some information from a string.

I would like for the id in a string in below pattern:
case:123455

It is embedded in a string like below:

```
This is a string. We want case:12345 and case:5656759 in the title 2.
```

I would like to extract the id 12345 & 565675 from the string. The occurrence of 'case' is dynamic, can be none, can appear 1 or more than 1 in a string.
I need help with the regex syntax to extract the info.

The following cases should be captured :

```
case:12345, case :12345, case: 12345, case : 12345, Case:12345, CASE:12345
```

Comment: you said `case` may or maynot present then how we find the number?

Comment: If case is not present, then return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a look-behind and `\d+`:

```
(?i)(?<=\bcase:)\d+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cbcase%3a)%5cd%2b&i=This+is+a+string.+we+want+case%3a12345+and+case%3a5656759+in+the+title+2.)

This regex will match *1 or more digits that appear after a literal string `case:` where `case` is a whole word*.

In case you need a version with capturing group, here it is:

```
(?i)\bcase:(\d+)
```

The value you need will be stored in capturing group 1.

**UPDATE**

To allow optional spaces in your pattern, use either

```
(?i)(?<=\bcase\s*:\s*)\d+
```

Or a version without lookbehind:

```
(?i)\bcase\s*:\s*(\d+)
```

**Making the pattern case-insensitive**

The `(?i)` inline option/flag makes the pattern case-insensitive, it will match `CASE` and `cAsE`. If you want to only match `Case` and `CASE` and `case`, you need to use `(?:[cC]ase|CASE)`.

Comment: My regex does not allow empty results, and matches `case` as a whole word.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? Is there anything else I should account for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But 1 more question. I would like to match if an empty space appear after case or : For example. case : 12345 or case:12345 or case: 12345 or case :12345, it will return me 12345. is this possible?

Comment: I added that solution for both regex variants. Note that `\s` matches any whitespace, so if you only want to match `case : 1234` with regular spaces either use a literal space " ", or use hex notation `\x20`.

Comment: And I suppose you are aware of how to declare regex in C#: verbatim string literals are the most convenient way: `@"\bcase..."`.

Comment: I added the example of how to make the pattern case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
string regex = @"\s(?i)case\s{0,1}:\s{0,1}(\d+)";
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zU1lW7/5)

Comment: This will also match `cornercase:sometext` and will capture an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @greenfeet. anyway to avoid empty string?

Comment: Now, it requires a whitespace to be in front of `case`. And still captures an empty string if there are no digits after `case:`.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks! fixed it again but left the space because I think that's intended

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But 1 more question. I would like to match if an empty space appear after case or : For example. case : 12345 or case:12345 or case: 12345 or case :12345 should retunr me 12345. is this possible?

Comment: Sorry last question promise. anyway to make the string 'case' not case sensitive?